# Does "le Français [...] venait d'être père" mean "the Frenchman was a father-to-be"?

Tags: grammaire

In my dictionary, *venir de* only means *to come from*.

I also don't think this is the *venir + infinitive* structure, which means *to be going to*.

Then the [headline](http://www.lefigaro.fr/international/2013/07/28/01003-20130728ARTFIG00065-drame-ferroviaire-en-espagne-le-francais-tue-venait-d-etre-pere.php) should probably have been *Il vient être père*, with no *de* between *venir* and *être*.

So does *le Français [...] venait d'être père* mean *the Frenchman was a father-to-be*?

Comment: *Aller + infinitive* is similar to *to be going to*. *Venir + infinitive* is quite the opposite actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[***Venir de + infinitive***](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/venir_de) is used to expressed recent past. So in this case, it means “The Frenchman [...] just became a father.“

> *Ma chatte vient d’avoir des petits.*
>
> My cat just had kittens.

***Venir + infinitive*** means to *to come and do something*

> *Viens voir les petits chats.*
>
> Come and see the kitties.

or *to come in order to do something*.

> *Je viens voir les chatons.*
>
> I come to see the kittens.

*To go to*, is be ***aller + infinitive***.

> Je vais voir les chatons.
>
> I’m going to see the kittens.

*To be going to* or *also* is ***aller + infinitive***.

> Ma chatte va avoir des petits.
>
> Ma cat is going to have kittens.